# Help with closed form math induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $a_k = 5a_{k-1}$ and $a_0=11$ Prove using mathematical induction that the closed form for this sequence is $a_n = 11\cdot 5^n$. Please help I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basis step: $a_0 = 11 = 11\cdot 5^0$.

Induction step.  Assume for a particular $n$ that $a_n = 11\cdot 5^n$. Then $a_{n+1} = ?$

Comment: Got it! Thanks a bunch!